# How to horizontally align equations in multicols package

Tags: multicol

I'm using the `multicols` package to write formulas side by side, as

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{eqnarray}
...
\end{eqnarray}
\columnbreak
\begin{eqnarray}
...
\end{eqnarray}
\end{multicols}
```

but they are found  not to be horizontally aligned. 
The text is less than a page, so I want to use `multicols` only for a fraction of the page.

How can I obtain this?

Comment: If you want to center two formulas on a row, why not using `\begin{align*}f(x)&=x+1; & g(x)&=x+2.\end{align*}`?

Comment: It's a quite good solution. Thanks, I didn't know it.

Comment: Please provide your code or at least the edited screenshot of the output you want.

Comment: I tried but I cannot upload images because I have less than 10 in reputation, however I have added the code.

Comment: `eqnarray` should not be used.

Comment: Use `align` to avoid some bad effects of `eqnarray`.

Comment: @Bugbusters Ok. However if I had known `align`, I wouldn't have the need of answering :-) (is it bad if I used smiles?)

Comment: I gave a comment based on your code above. It is recommended to smile. :-)

Comment: [Avoid eqnarray!](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is far from clear (it always helps to post a complete example) however if you just want two equations side by side you do not need `multicol` You may prefer

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\begin{equation}...\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\begin{equation}...\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Thanks, it a good general solution, but in my simply case the use of \begin{align*} ... \end{align*}, as suggest by Sigur, is probably the best way.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\begin{align}
v_t &= v_0 +at\\
x   &= v_0t + \tfrac{1}{2} at^2
\end{align}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: there's excess space above the math.  this seems to be a function of `multicols` since it happens also with `\[ ... \]`.  maybe should be reported as a bug, or at least a misfeature.  actually, this approach is the opposite of what is requested, namely the text single column, and the math side-by-side.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: You are correct. I did not read the question well. :-)